# Evaluating equation inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

How do I fix the following code:

```
A[z_] = B*z^2;
Manipulate[FindMinimum[A[z], {z, 1}], {B, 1, 10}]
```

In particular, what is the best way to force substitution of B in A[z] inside FindMinimum?  Following [How to | Evaluate Expressions inside Dynamic or Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/EvaluateExpressionsInsideDynamicOrManipulate.html), I tried the following which failed:

```
Manipulate[FindMinimum[With[{B = B}, A[z]], {z, 1}], {B, 1, 10}]
```

The following works, but seems clunky:

```
Manipulate[FindMinimum[A[z] /. B -> C, {z, 1}], {C, 1, 10}]
```

Actually I want something like this, but simpler, without all the substitutions:

```
Manipulate[
 Table[FindMinimum[A[z] /. B -> C, {z, y}], {y, {1,2}}], {C, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Linked topic should answer your question, let me know if you disagree. And welcome to Mathematica.Stackexchange :)

Comment: `f[x_, b_] := x^2 + b*x;
    xm[b_] := x /. Last[FindMinimum[f[x, b], {x, 1}]] ;   
    Manipulate[xm[b], {b, 0, 10}]`